# Postgres how to create table with automatic create_by

Tags: postgresql

If I want to create a table with column create_by automatically filled with the user who create the entry, what is the DDL look like?
Wonder whether Postgres can do this similar to create_at

```
e.g. create_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
```

kind of thing.

Comment: There is `current_user` you can use

Comment: `create_by text NOT NULL DEFAULT current_user`

Comment: create_at timestamp default current_timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3a66a/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
    (
        id serial primary key
      , "bar" varchar(1)
      , created_by text NOT NULL DEFAULT current_user
      , created_at timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp
    )
;

INSERT INTO foo
    ("bar")
VALUES
    ('a'),
    ('b'),
    ('c')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from foo
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3a66a/1/0)**:

```
| id | bar |    created_by |                  created_at |
|----|-----|---------------|-----------------------------|
|  1 |   a | user_17_3a66a | 2017-11-04T05:05:18.161681Z |
|  2 |   b | user_17_3a66a | 2017-11-04T05:05:18.161681Z |
|  3 |   c | user_17_3a66a | 2017-11-04T05:05:18.161681Z |
```